# Passing Integer of type 32 to the defined stored procedure in mysql of datatype INT

Tags: c#, mysql

I am executing my stored procedure from c# and passing the param int of type Int 32 and in my sql db. I have a param which accepts datatype INT:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `SetProc`(PersonCount INT )
```

Will it work, as I read that in c# int 32 is signed whereas in mysql state it as unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass in a `Uint32` which is an unsigned int with range 0 to 2^32 - 1.

BTW: According to [the MySQL 5 Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html), `INT` defaults to a signed int. Only when adding the optional (nonstandard) attribute `UNSIGNED` it is an unsigned int.